# How to configure correctly Wordpress Multi Site on Amazon AWS EC2?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multisite

I created an amazon ec2 t2micro instance and installed on it Wordpress Multi Site (Bitnami) from the aws marketplace. After the installation I couldn't add a site to the network.
I decided to change the mode to sub_folder instead of sub_domain, so I connected through ssh to edit the wp-config file.

I changed `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);` to `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);`

After this editing nothing changed so I decided to look for the .htaccess file. I edited the htaccess this way

```
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`
```

Now I'm trying again to add a site to the network but after the creation of the new site I can't see the dashboard.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Missed these commands from bitnami documentation

  ```
  sudo ./bnconfig --machine_hostname my-domain.com

  sudo mv bnconfig bnconfig.disabled
  ```
- Assigned the DNS to Route53 setting custom DNS on my namecheap account.
  Added an A type DNS Record for the specific subdomain that points to my Elastic Ip Address.

It works now!